# Using radio button to set cookie preferences?

Tags: php

I have these 4 radio buttons in which i am submitting to a validatepreferences.php which is the php code below however i am struggling to understand why when i click submit nothing is going through the if statement therefore not giving me my cookie in which to change images based on user input

```
<input type="radio" name="radioimage"><img class="prefimage" src="../images/image1.jpg">
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="radioimage"><img class="prefimage" src="../images/image2.jpg">
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="radioimage"><img class="prefimage" src="../images/image3.jpg">
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="radioimage"> No Picture
```

I think the php code must have an error or my if is not right altough i cannot see it.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['radioimage'])){
        $radioimage = $_POST['radioimage'];
        if ($radioimage == "0" || $radioimage == "1" || $radioimage == "2" || $radioimage =="3") {
        setcookie("image", $radioimage, time()+300);
    }
}
    ?>
```

Comment: I found one error which was a missing { but still not going through the if

Comment: It goes through the first if but not the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not giving the radiobuttons values in the form. You have to give them values  so you can retrieve those values with $_POST in validatepreferences.php. So the HTML should be:

```
                    <input type="radio" name="radioimage" value="1"><img class="prefimage" src="../images/image1.jpg">
                    <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="radioimage" value="2"><img class="prefimage" src="../images/image2.jpg">
                    <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="radioimage" value="3"><img class="prefimage" src="../images/image3.jpg">
                    <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="radioimage" value="4"> No Picture
```